# Using personal laptop in corporate network getting so many SSL error

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ssl, intranet

How come using personal laptop in the corporate network to access intranet or Outlook get so many SSL error/untrusted certificate? Whereas using company issued laptop never gets error. Is it because the company one has already joined the domain? Or has installed all company self-certified certificates?

According to this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/how-to-install-certificate-in-ie9-on-windows-7/6387dca1-4764-4fad-a7d0-c268139d08d6?msgId=e2049249-cdc8-4dcd-8a66-54cef8fe9966), there seems to be no way to install/import company certificates on personal laptop. So I will need to do extra 1-2 clicks on "proceed with untrusted certificates (or something similar)" for accessing Outlook or intranet every time!

Or is there any way to install/import the certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AD domain, the certificate server is automagically trusted by domain clients.  As your PC is not a domain client, it doesn't see the CA.  The thread you reference seems to say you *can* import the CA cert.  I would think that should work.  Have you tried it?

Comment: if you read this "Unfortunately, after IE9 is reopened by the Standard user, the certificate is not installed so the warnings continue.". This is what happens to me too. Another quick question, can my personal laptop join corporate domain without IT's help? What could I need to successfully proceed this task?

Comment: You really should be talking to IT.  Not sure how big your company is, but you could be blowing several security policies if you go too much further.